# How can you link a type's values sequentially to integers?

Tags: ada

I am trying to have a program that takes a number from the user (from 1 - 12) and it will return that month's short form, eg: if you write `1` it will return `JAN` etc.

I have the following:

```
type Month_Type is (JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC);
```

but how do I link this to `userMonth : Integer;`. I thought something like Month_Type(userMonth) but this didn't work and gave me errors. The only other thing I can think of is to have a loop for each Month_Type and have a counter in there so that it matches. But this seems messy and not very efficient, there must be a better way.

Comment: Homework? You might be interested in the positions that `JAN` and to forth have in the type. For that, have a look at the 'Pos attribute. Or simply use a conditional that reflects what you wrote: **if** … 1 **then** … **return** `JAN`…

Comment: Why are you using `Integer` for the input?  If the user only is allowed to enter `1 .. 12`, then you should use an appropriate type: `type Month_Number is range 1 .. 12;`.

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen what benefits will that have? What if a 13 is entered? will it error out?

Comment: Exactly.  So you avoid incorrect entries.

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen i've started to incorporate your suggestion of using a range, which looks like it makes a subtype of Integer, this means my `Int_Io.get` doesn't work, i'm guessing I need to do a custom type.get, which I can see in your answer below how to do. but I get an error with that, my guess is that is because a range of intgers is not an enumeration_IO. What do I use instead?

Comment: ... drum-roll ... `Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO`. :-)  When you are programming in Ada, it is useful to have the Ada Language Reference Manual (http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-TTL.html) around for looking such things up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Among the [*Operations of Discrete Types*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-3-5-5.html), the attribute `'Val` denotes a function that returns a value of the type `Month_Type` whose position number equals the value of the argument passed to it. For example, the expression `Month_Type'Val(0)` would evaluate to `JAN`.

Note that the internal code used by the attribute is unaffected by an [*Enumeration Representation Clause*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-13-4.html). Given a declaration such as `userMonth : constant := 1`, use the expression `Month_Type'Val(userMonth - 1)`.

When using a representation clause with [GNAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNAT), the implementation defined attribute [`'Enum_Val`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gnat_rm/Attribute-Enum_005fVal.html#Attribute-Enum_005fVal) denotes a function that "returns the enumeration value whose representation matches the argument." Using the representation clause suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42729223/230513), the expression `Month_Type'Enum_Val(userMonth)` would evaluate to `JAN` without adjustment.

Answer (score 7):

In Ada you can do it much easier:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Demo is
   type Month_Type is (Jan, Feb, Mar, [...], Dec);
   package Month_Text_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO (Month_Type);
   Input : Month_Type;
begin
   Month_Text_IO.Get (Input);
end Demo;
```

No need to handle integer values in between.

Answer (score 3):

As a complement of the other answers, you can also use the Ada representation clauses to match your enumerate with the *intput/output* values that you like.

This is useful if you need to interface your code with other software that might be not coded in Ada.

There are a few limitations with this : if my memories are good, you need to have ascending numbers.

So :

```
type Month_Type is (JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC);
for Month_Type use (
        JAN => 1,
        FEB => 2,
        ...);
```

Comment: But then you would have to use a `Unchecked_Conversion` to map from an integer type to `Month_Type`. :-(

Comment: See trashgod’s answer above for GNAT’s `’Enum_Val`.